# Sonar failed with an API incompatibility for Absent Code attribute

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

One of my fellow developers created a new application the other day and now I can't get a good Sonar compile. I've tried a number of documented workarounds/solutions to this sort of Absent Code error, but haven't found the right combination. The project includes the glassfish and glassfish-embedded-all jars that are supposed to provide an implementation for the javax-servlet. They are set to scope test.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried this one too with no luck:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <!-- exclude code absent api -->                                    
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExclude>                                
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-web-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the error with Maven 3.0.4:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project Filters: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.6/sonar-scanner-api-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.avaya.zephyr.services.sample_services.Authorization:Filters:3.4.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
```

The project's pom looks mostly like another similar project that isn't having the error. It does, however, have a warning:

```
Apr 20, 2017 4:52:16 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver visit
WARNING: Could not find class myBetterClass, due to: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Application
```

I thought that providing the glassfish embedded jar was supposed to solve that sort of issue. (Maybe there is a newer version of glassfish needed?)

Comment: Can you run with mvn -X and show the complete output? And are by any chance still running Java 6?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5787? But 3.0.4 should actually not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to resolve this by trying out the following:

1. Update Maven to `3.5.0` to maintain the Maven to its latest version.
2. You can follow the [matrix here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) to see if the version used by you is compatible or not. From the logs, your build is using an [older version of the plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)

   > .scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2

   Try executing

   ```
   mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar
   ```
3. Make sure your exclusions are marked within the `<properties>` of the pom.xml as

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <sonar.host.url>http://www.example.com/</sonar.host.url>
       <sonar.exclusions>some/path/to/javax/javaee-api/**, some/path/to/javax:javaee-web-api</sonar.exclusions>
   </properties>
   ```

Comment: Do you have an explanation of why this error occurs and why the exclusion is an acceptable solution? Indeed, I can solve the problem with an exclusion, but it's not really satisfactory to me. It's like having a compile error and "solving" it by commenting out the problematic line ;-)

Comment: @dokaspar Since the `sonar-maven-plugin` is in use the [documentation from the source as linked in answer](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ProjectanalyzedwithMaven3) states configuring the sonar attributes into `properties` itself.